# Can you trust a regression model that has an insignificant F-test and insignificant coefficients?

Tags: regression, f-test

I have a regression with an insignificant F-stat. In an even stricter regression (with fewer observations), the F-stat becomes inestimable (denoted by Stata with dots in F and Prob > F).

My question relates to whether I can interpret the individual coefficients, which are insignificant in both regressions: As in "none of the independent variables are statistically significant to the dependent variable."

The null results would greatly help my paper.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interpret insignificant results as not being able to reject null. That would be the standard practice.

However, it’s worrying that you say in some of your model F-Statistics becomes in-estimable. That should not happen just because there aren’t statistically significant relationships. Even when model cannot explain virtually any variation in the data you should be able to have F-Statistics.

Hence you should investigate that problem further. Do you have insufficient amount of observations? If so you can’t even interpret it as not being able to reject null.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! My F-stat is first insignificant and then even drops out because of the quantity of observations. Essentially, my independent variable is a percentage point difference in prices from my experiment. Analyzing the behavior with changes of 10, I have 652 observations. Analyzing changes of at least 15, I only have 342 observations. Another issue is that I cluster on the individual level, so in the first regression I have 380 clusters (i.e., 380 people who even saw changes of 10), while in the regression with 15, I have 253 clusters.

Comment: Clustering the standard errors on the individual level is necessary to avoid an inflation of the individual t-stats as the observations are not truly independent from each other. Please don't say that I need more observations with changes of 10 and 15 as the data is already collected and I cannot get more data. In the paper, I am hoping to say despite the overall model's insignificance as denoted by the F-stat, I am not interested in collectively examining that all coefficients are equal to zero. I am interested in the individual coefficients in that they are not significant for the dep var